# Can no longer concatenate two data frames containing time-stamps in an similar column when switching from 2.0.3 to 2.1.4 +

Tags: pandas, concatenation

I have two data frames with some common columns (including columns with timestamps) and others unique to either. I used to be able to concatenate these two dataframes (using pandas 2.0.3), however, after upgrading to 2.2.0 I run into errors looking like

```
File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py:393, in concat(objs, axis, join, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    378     copy = False
    380 op = _Concatenator(
    381     objs,
    382     axis=axis,
   (...)
    390     sort=sort,
    391 )
--> 393 return op.get_result()

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py:680, in _Concatenator.get_result(self)
    676             indexers[ax] = obj_labels.get_indexer(new_labels)
    678     mgrs_indexers.append((obj._mgr, indexers))
--> 680 new_data = concatenate_managers(
    681     mgrs_indexers, self.new_axes, concat_axis=self.bm_axis, copy=self.copy
    682 )
    683 if not self.copy and not using_copy_on_write():
    684     new_data._consolidate_inplace()

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/concat.py:189, in concatenate_managers(mgrs_indexers, axes, concat_axis, copy)
    187     fastpath = blk.values.dtype == values.dtype
    188 else:
--> 189     values = _concatenate_join_units(join_units, copy=copy)
    190     fastpath = False
    192 if fastpath:

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/concat.py:486, in _concatenate_join_units(join_units, copy)
    483     concat_values = ensure_block_shape(concat_values, 2)
    485 else:
--> 486     concat_values = concat_compat(to_concat, axis=1)
    488 if empty_dtype != empty_dtype_future:
    489     if empty_dtype == concat_values.dtype:
    490         # GH#39122, GH#40893

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/concat.py:132, in concat_compat(to_concat, axis, ea_compat_axis)
    130     to_concat_eas = cast("Sequence[ExtensionArray]", to_concat)
    131     cls = type(to_concat[0])
--> 132     return cls._concat_same_type(to_concat_eas)
    133 else:
    134     to_concat_arrs = cast("Sequence[np.ndarray]", to_concat)

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimelike.py:2251, in TimelikeOps._concat_same_type(cls, to_concat, axis)
   2245 @classmethod
   2246 def _concat_same_type(
   2247     cls,
   2248     to_concat: Sequence[Self],
   2249     axis: AxisInt = 0,
   2250 ) -> Self:
-> 2251     new_obj = super()._concat_same_type(to_concat, axis)
   2253     obj = to_concat[0]
   2255     if axis == 0:
   2256         # GH 3232: If the concat result is evenly spaced, we can retain the
   2257         # original frequency

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/_mixins.py:230, in NDArrayBackedExtensionArray._concat_same_type(cls, to_concat, axis)
    227     dtypes = {str(x.dtype) for x in to_concat}
    228     raise ValueError("to_concat must have the same dtype", dtypes)
--> 230 return super()._concat_same_type(to_concat, axis=axis)
```

I've tried variations of using `ignore_index=True, sort=True` etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please [mre]: can't see the line of code that raised the error, nor a representative data sample

Answer (score 0):

The underlying issue was that the time resolution between the timestamps in the two data frames was different (one using micro-second and the other using nano-second). I should have noted in the original question that both data frames were first written then read back in using `<dataframe>.to_parquet` and `pd.read_parquet` respectively. Interestingly, both dataframes had nano-second resolution when created however one (`df_1`) was not requiring the full precision of the nano second range). When `df_1` when written out, it seems the resolution was bumped down to micro-second. As best I can tell, the issue arose from a change in the ability to concatenate timestamp series of different precision (I think this was the issue based off of https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/53641).
My solution was to write out both parquets using `to_parquet(<filename>, use_deprecated_int96_timestamps=True)` and force the same precision for both.